# Definition of “inner-hom” of vector bundles

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, vector-bundles

I am reading a paper. In that, for vector bundles $A, B\rightarrow M$ over a manifold $M$, they use the term “inner-hom bundle” and denote by $[A,B]\rightarrow M$.

Is this a standard notation? What does it mean, where can I find details about that?

I know what a hom vector bundle, obtained from two vector bundles over same manifold, is. But, never heard of inner-hom vector bundle.

Any references are appreciated.

Comment: What is the paper?

Comment: Hello @MichaelAlbanese, https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.07152   page 12

Comment: This is just another name for the "hom vector bundle". The reason for the name is that it is the inner-hom (a.k.a. internal hom) with respect to the tensor product of vector bundles: using your notation, there are natural isomorphisms $hom(C,[A,B]) \cong hom(C \otimes A , B)$.

Comment: @AaronMazel-Gee I am 95% convinced.. :) I am looking at https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/internal+hom to know more about that... can you think of any other place where this is mentioned..

Comment: Well, internal hom shows up everywhere! This can arise whenever you have a category equipped with a monoidal structure. I agree that nLab can be challenging to learn from. There is the wikipedia page (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hom_functor#Internal_Hom_functor), but it is brief. This doesn't seem to be mentioned in Eilenberg & Mac Lane's book "Categories for the working mathematician". A comprehensive treatment of this phenomenon -- which gives rise to the theory of _enriched categories_ is in Kelley's book "Basic concepts of enriched category theory".

Comment: @AaronMazel-Gee Thanks for the suggestion about Kelley's book. :) I will see that :)